# Existence of such a function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

I am supposed to construct a function $f \in C_c^1((-\frac{3R}{4},\frac{3R}{4}))$ such that $f|_{(-\frac{R}{2},\frac{R}{2})}=1$ and $|f'(x)| \le \frac{4}{R}$ for almost all $x \in (-R,R)?$

I currently don't see how to do it, but often there are some nice tricks how such functions can actually be constructed and maybe I am lucky and anybody here knows how it can be done?

Comment: Do you know convolution?

Comment: @JohnMa yes, I do. but I do not see what I should convolve here?

Comment: Hint: such a function does not exist. Try to prove that. (Assume such an $f$ existed, and find a contradiction.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a function cannot exist. Let $f$ satisfies your condition. Then as it has compact support, there is $x \in \left( -\frac{3R}{4} ,-\frac{R}{2}\right)$ so that $f(x) = 0$. Then as $f$ is $C^1$,

$$ 1= f\left(-\frac{R}{2}\right) - f(x) = \int_{-\frac{R}{2}}^x f'(s) ds$$

If $|f'|\le 4/R$. Then

$$\left| \int_{-\frac{R}{2}}^x f'(s)\right| \le \int_{-\frac{R}{2}}^x |f'(s)|\le \left( -\frac{R}{2} -x\right)\frac{4}{R} <1$$

Which is a contradiction to the first equation.

**Remark** For any $C>4$, one can use convolution to find $f \in C^\infty_c$ so that $|f'|\le C/R$: First take $g$ to be the continuous function which is

\begin{cases}
1 & \text{ on } (-\frac{R}{2}-\delta, \frac{R}{2} +\delta),\\
\text{linear}  & \text{ on }(-\frac{3R}{4} + \delta, -\frac{R}{2}-\delta)\cup (\frac{R}{2} + \delta, \frac{3R}{4}-\delta)\\
0 &\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}

Then the slope of $g$ is smaller then $\frac{1}{\frac{R}{4}-2\delta}$. Then $\delta$ is small, this term is smaller then $C' <C$ when $C>4.

Now let $f = g * \eta_\epsilon$, where $\epsilon < \delta$. Then by choosing a smaller enough $\epsilon$, $f$ would satisfies your conditions.

Comment: could you give me an idea how such a convolution argument could work? just for the sake of completeness

Comment: @ConanOBrien : Please see the edit.